# Delphi - Split Lines(Program not responding), not spliting file size (TTHREAD)

Tags: delphi

Hope everyone is doing great.
I just have one question , in Delphi programming...
I've a Memo that loads me a file .txt , and it contains big lines , like 50,000Lines....

SO I want to split thes lines to 5000line then loading them into a new Memo.
for example for the first split , it will split 5000lines on a new file text then loading it on a new memo , after the load (deleting the file of 5000) , and of course it will be 45000 for the big LINES.

the second split it will split 5000 from the 45,000 , it will be 40,000 on the big lines  , 5000on the new Lines (file text) .

THE REASON why i want to split the lines on file text then loading it , because the program isn't answering (not responding) when i split the files into the memo .

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var count,i ,X,m:integer;
begin
Memo2.Clear;
Label1.Caption:=IntToStr(Memo1.Lines.Count) ;
if Memo1.Lines.Count > 5000 then
X:=5000
else X:= Memo1.Lines.Count ;
for  count:=0 to x do
  begin

  Memo2.lines.add(Memo1.lines.Strings[0]);
  Memo1.Lines.Delete(0);

             Memo2.Text:=Trim(Memo2.text);

end;
end;
```

This is the code i'm using to split small Lines to small other lines ...

In a Memo , but when you have 1 million of lines , the program will stop answering.

i added the trim(memo2.text) ; To delete the blank line at the End.

So how i can do the spliting of Lines ,not of File SIZE(because it will destroy lines) ... how i can do the split of big lines like i said to file text then loading it and deleting it , then when i re-click a button it will do the same operation with the others lines ....

I know that we must using TThread class , but i don't know how to make it happen with my code... Thank's!

Thank you.

Comment: Threads are not the solution, as they can't interact with GUI controls without synchronizing with the main thread (which defeats the purpose of using threads). Why do you need to use a memo to split content? The user clearly can't see all of the memo controls at the same time. What is the intent of your code? Display has nothing to do with *splitting to text files*.

Comment: I'll try again. It's not clear that you need a memo (a visual control) at all from your post. It's not clear whether you're trying to display content to the user, or whether you're simply (and wrongly) trying to use a memo for the wrong thing. So I'll ask yet again: WHAT IS YOUR ACTUAL GOAL? Do you want to display content in the memo to the user? Do you want to play with the content of the tile? Can you actually read the questions I keep asking you that you seem to keep ignoring? **WHAT EXACTLY ARE YOU TRYING TO DO?** If you can't be bothered to explain that, your question doesn't belong here.

Comment: Clarify your question to indicate whether your goial is to **display the content of the memo to the user* (the proper use(, or whether you're using the memo (incorrectly) as a kludge to perform some other task. Your post and comments so far don't clarify whether you're simply properly using the UI control or if you're doing something totally wrong that users a UI control in the process, and repeated attempts to ask you to clarify seem to be failing. **WHICH OF THOSE THINGS IS IT YOU;'RE WANTING TO DO?* They're separate and distinct things, so there's a single choice. Which ONE do you choose?

Comment: Okay , forget about Memo , it's just an example MEMO as you are so Persistant . my question : how with Delphi we can split big Lines of TEXT FILE , to small Lines ONES , without getting our program not responding? it's a great question no ?

Comment: Finally we have progress, because you're paging attention. :-) You can split a text file into many small ones in several ways (none of which involve a user inferface). Now start over with your questioon: I have a text file that has XXXXXX number of lines in it. Here's what I need to do with each line. How can I do that?

Comment: For future reference: When someone asks you to explain or clarify something, based on your question, do so, without complaining. They're asking for that information in order to help you. If you don't want to partic9pathe, make it clear by either not posting here in the first place or by stating *I DON'T WANT TO HEAR YOUR ANSERS* in your postl

Comment: Threads are not the answer. Memos are not the answer.

Comment: yes , so IN delphi you have the code of spliting big Lines into small lines? , And not spliting file big size into small sizes ...

Comment: @JohnGOLFOil: Yes, I have that code, and I'll be glad to share it **once you make up your mind about what your question is asking and [edit]it to make it clear (as I've asked several times previouslly).

Comment: @JohnGOLFOil, reading a text file that large is done in a blink of your eye.

Comment: @John You won't easily do the processing quickly in a GUI control. Do any processing outside of a GUI control and splat final answer into any controls only once you know it.

Comment: My other advice is that you should not decide that you know the answer and then ask the question. If you know the answer already as you claim here, don't waste time by asking. If you are keen to learn and have an open mind, please do ask.

Comment: If you stop playing games and make clear what you're asking, we can probably help. I for one routinely handle files that are larger than 1GB, and allow the user to browse through the content.. If you will **simply make clear what you're asking**, as I've asked several times before, I'm certain someone here can help. If you continue to be obstinate, then let's close this question and move on to people who really want our help

Comment: Everyone is saying, what you want what you want -_________-" i've said! before, spliting lines from .txt file to another txt file , taking 5000 from 50,000 , so the old file will be 45,000. shit!

Comment: John, since you don't want to keep that temporary text file, what's the point in creating one? Use a buffer in memory instead like David pointed out in his answer.

Comment: The reason of deleting the file after creating it , because when i split the 5000 first lines from the 50,000.... it will creat a file .txt , i'll load this file in a Memo , to work with it ... then deleting the temporary file text after the load , and when i reclick the button it will split another 5000 in the temporary.txt , then i'll load it in a MEMO ... repeat repeat repeat repeat ...

Answer (score 2):

Threading is not the answer to the problem. You should not need threads for this task. The problem is here:

```
Memo1.Lines.Delete(0);
```

Performing this in a loop is exceptionally expensive for a memo. The first part of the text is removed, and the rest moved up.

The best approach is:

1. Move the entire source to a `TStringList`.
2. Process the first 5000 lines of that string list into a single string.
3. Add that entire string in one go to the memo using `SelText := ...`.

When you are done, clear the original memo with one call.

Comment: Nice answer! but SelText makes the lines into one line, no? and if i take 5000lines , can i deleting them from the TsringList? as i can take another 5000new in the second time,i click a button?...

Comment: No. Include line breaks when you concatenate the 5000 source lines. Then it's all good.

Comment: That's not really what this site is about. Sorry.

Comment: but i need to test what you've said, any code please? as i can test and see if it works really? because i have no knowledge with the TStringList.thank's!

Comment: Then it's time for you to learn. This site is intended to be used by programmers. If you don't know how to write code, and learn, then it's not for you. You need to hire a programmer in that case.

Comment: Your answer isn't complete, i can't approve :D

Comment: @DavidHeffernan +1 There's nothing more you could have done here. You have written clearly what is likely the responsible cause of the slowdown and you have also presented a good solution. The question asker seems very immature and desperate for someone to do all the work for them.

Comment: @JohnGOLFOil - Please stop harassing David by demanding that he provide code. He's given you an answer, and it's up to you to implement it. We are all volunteers here. Be glad that he took the time to answer you in any way. These comments need to stop now.

Comment: He started spamming me on Facebook. He called me a racist at least 10 times, and now he can't understand I won't be his friend.

Comment: @Jens Very hard to understand. Probably needs therapy.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before

> Use TStringList to load and process your data, TMemo to display it.

And remember : If you can't mak it, fake it!

And you can't load 50000 lines into a **standard VCL control** in reasonable time.

So I've made you a small sample application showing you how to fake it:

You need to add ERROR handing to the demo, I just took the shortest and most optimistic path.

First I needed some data so I generated a file with random data:

```
procedure TForm25.GenereateTextFile(const aLines: Integer);
var
  Buffer: TStringlist;
  Line: string;
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  Buffer := TStringlist.Create;
  try
    for i := 1 to aLines do
    begin
      SetLength(Line, Random(200));
      for j := 1 to Length(Line) do
        Line[j] := Chr(ord('a') + Random(26));
      Buffer.Add(Line);
    end;

    Buffer.SaveToFile('dummy.txt');
  finally
    Buffer.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And I call it form FormCreate:

```
procedure TForm25.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GenereateTextFile(50000);
end;
```

Then we need to generate some GUI inorder to display the file:

Put a TTimer on your form and set it's  Interval to 50, and assign an OnTimer event to it

procedure TForm25.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False; 
  GenerateGUI(Self, 'dummy.txt');
end;

Only thing left is to generate the actual GUI:

```
procedure TForm25.GenerateGUI(const aForm: TForm; const aFileName: TFilename; aLinesPerPage: Integer = 5000);
var
  Buffer: TStringlist;
  Tmp: TStringlist;
  i, j: Integer;
  PageControl: TPageControl;
  TabSheet: TTabSheet;
  Memo: TMemo;
begin
  Buffer := TStringlist.Create;
  Buffer.LoadFromFile(aFileName);
  Buffer.BeginUpdate;

  PageControl := TPageControl.Create(aForm);
  PageControl.Parent := aForm;
  PageControl.Align := alClient;
  i := 0;

  for i := 0 to (Buffer.Count div aLinesPerPage) - 1 do
  begin
    TabSheet := TTabSheet.Create(PageControl);
    TabSheet.PageControl := PageControl;
    TabSheet.Caption := Format('Lines %d to %d', [i * aLinesPerPage, (i + 1) * aLinesPerPage - 1]);

    Memo := TMemo.Create(TabSheet);
    Memo.Parent := TabSheet;
    Memo.Align := alClient;

    j := 0;

    Tmp := TStringlist.Create;
    Tmp.BeginUpdate;
    Application.ProcessMessages;

    while j < aLinesPerPage do
    begin
      Tmp.Add(Buffer[0]);
      Buffer.Delete(0);
      inc(j);
    end;

    Memo.Lines.Assign(Tmp);
    Tmp.Free;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
  FreeAndNil(Buffer);
end;
```

You'll see the pages shows up one by one and displays data.

The reason why it shows up one by one is because I call `Application.ProcessMessages;` it slows things down a littlebit bot not much, and you tell your user that the program is alive.

Comment: i don't understand? HOW I CAN CALL THE PROCEDURE FROM A BUTTON? , you mean when i click a button i enable the timer?

Comment: Place a button on your form and click on it twice and then write this code: 

GenerateGUI(Self, 'dummy.txt');

Comment: what for dummy.txt,i can bring mine 50,000lines? or i must do the first code to generate these randoms lines? because i don't need randoms lines...

Comment: Replace dummy.txt with the real name of your file.

Comment: but the first code and second , i don't need it then ? i don't only third code then ?

Comment: i need only the BUTTON CODE AND THE LAST CODE ? NOT THE FIRST AND SECOND THEN , for my case ? because i've already the file text , no need to generate it , true ?

Comment: Correct no need to generate a file first. I only did that because I needed some data

Comment: Oh nice! So it will"cut" ," cut i said please " 5000lines from 50,0000 each time i click a button ? , can you do for us please a .pas + .dfm ? a hole project , as we can test it please .... add me on Skype bro .

Comment: Can you upload your test file sone where? Then I'll make you a complete example

Comment: @Jens Please reconsider. Please do not feed the vampires.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt I tested your code!it's amazin' working very well,but i've 2  questions about your code please, first question: when i click a button it loads some indexes like lines from 0-5000 ,5000 to 10,000, how i can call these indexes? or working with the memo in the index of 0-5000 for example? . QUESTION2: why the last lines are deleted after the 50,000 , we don't get another 200lines or 232 last lines or 332 lines .....

Comment: I think we must do pagecontrol invisiblein the code to make it invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how essential the use of a TMemo is to your application, but if all you're wanting to do is to split a textfile into several files with the same number of lines in them (except maybe the final one, of course), you don't need a TMemo at all, nor indeed any Delphi container class like a TStringList or TStream.  The point is, you have a perfectly good container already, namely the file system.

Following is a Delphi console application which uses file access methods that were in Object Pascal since before Delphi (I can hear some Delphi fans tut-tutting about me showing you this way, but imo it does no harm to find out other, perfectly valid ways of doing things, especially as this one avoids getting into the semantics and usages of Delphi container classes).

Hopefully, how it works is self-evident.  After creating a test file, it reads it back, line-by-line and outputs it to a sequentially numbered output file until that has as many lines in it as you want, or there are no more lines left to read.  It takes 0.078 seconds from beginning to end on my portable.

Code:

```
program FileSplit;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

const
  MaxLines = 100000;
  LinesPerFile = 5000;
  BufferSize = 32768;

var
  MainFileName : String;

procedure CreateFile(AFileName : String);
var
  AFile : Text;
  Line : Integer;
  Buffer : Array[1..BufferSize] of Char;
  S : String;
begin
  AssignFile(AFile, AFileName);
  SetTextBuf(AFile, Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer));
  Rewrite(AFile);

  Line := 1;
  while Line <= MaxLines do begin
    S := Format('This is line: %d', [Line]);
    writeln(AFile, S);
    Inc(Line);
  end;
  Close(AFile);
end;

procedure SplitFile(AFileName : String);
var
  AFile : Text;
  SubFileNumber : Integer;
  Buffer : Array[1..BufferSize] of Char;

  procedure CreateSubFile(SubFileNumber : Integer);
  var
    OutFile : Text;
    OutBuffer : Array[1..BufferSize] of Char;
    SubFileName : String;
    S : String;
    Line : Integer;
  begin
    SubFileName := ExtractFilePath(AFileName) + IntToStr(SubFileNumber) + '.Txt';
    writeln(SubFileName);

    Assign(OutFile, SubFileName);
    SetTextBuf(OutFile, OutBuffer, SizeOf(OutBuffer));
    Rewrite(OutFile);

    Line := 1;

    // the following reads the input file a line at a time
    // and outputs it to the current output file
    // until there's nothing left to read or the lines
    // per output file is reached

    while (Line <= LinesPerFile) and not Eof(AFile) do begin
      readln(AFile, S);
      writeln(OutFile, S);
      Inc(Line);
    end;

    Close(OutFile);
  end;

begin
  Assign(AFile, AFileName);
  SetTextBuf(AFile, Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer));
  Reset(AFile);

  SubFileNumber := 1;
  while not Eof(AFile) do begin
    CreateSubFile(SubFileNumber);
    Inc(SubFileNumber);
  end;
  Close(AFile);
end;

begin
  MainFileName:= GetEnvironmentVariable('Temp');
  MainFileName := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(MainFileName);
  MainFileName := MainFileName + 'Main.Txt';

  CreateFile(MainFileName);
  writeln(Format('File %s created', [MainFileName]));

  SplitFile(MainFileName);
  readln;

end.
```

Comment: NICE CODE , just needs small changes...i want to split LINES, not the file SIZE, because it's diffrents terms,when you split lines you take lines from THE SOURCE, when you split file size it's diffrent between file and file you'll get your lines destroyed.........So i want to "CUT" 5000lines from the 50,000 SOURCE. when i click a button . and when i reclickit will takes 5000 from the 45,000, when i click third time it will take 5000 and it will rest 35,000 etc etc

Comment: I'm not sure what distinction you're trying to draw between "lines" and "size" - my code will work regardless of the length of individual lines.  But anyway ...

Comment: when you split big file SIZE, to small size files, between file and file you'll get the last line destroyed.   but when you take like 5000lines from 50,000 each time you click a button it will be so good(no destroyed lines). so your code do that job? (cutting 5000lines from 50,000lines for example)?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure you understand what's going on.  That code doesn't **destroy** anything at all, it just copies lines from one file to other files.  Btw, this reminds me (I wonder why?) of a thread here last week that was about "joining" memos together.  The use of memos in that case was completely unnecessary, too.  Anyway, I'm done.  Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You may be hitting the limits of tmemo (depends on which version of Delphi you are using).  Certainly it will take time to delete the first line from the tmemo, expecially 5000 times.

Would you consider using readln and writeln to memo 2 for the first 5000 lines and memo 2 for the rest, if present?

Comment: There are no *limtis of TMemo*. Since Windows 2000, there is no limit.

Comment: Yes, it takes time for deleting the first line true, that's why we have to use something tthread class , mean spliting into a file text, not into memo because it's using memory.

Comment: Yes , no limit on a TMemo , just if you add lines from Tstrings , for the load there's no limit

Comment: What i did with my code, was loading a file text in a MEMO1 first of all. so about 50,000of Lines...(and program when loads big files it start to block too), so in a MEMO2 i splited 5000Lines from the MEMO1. so 5000on the MEMO2 , 45,000lines on Memo1 NOW!!!!!....But it takes a lot of time to take these 5000lines from 50,000lines...i just want to make it more faster! so that's what i said TThread

Comment: @John Processing text in a GUI control is cripplingly slow. Deleting text from the top of a memo is slow. Don't do that.

Comment: Ho , so deleting and taking lines from the end is better?

Comment: No, forget the TMemo. It is NOT good if you want to process large data. Use TStringList to load and process your data, TMemo to display it.