# x64 debugging fail when Getit is disabled

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I always try to disable unused packages to save some IDE memory. So in XE8u1 I try to disable GetIt (I never use it) by renaming "$(BDS)\Bin\GetIt220.bpl" in registry to "_GetIt". After that GetIt desappears from tools as expected, but strange issue appears: when I try to debug x64 apps I get "disconnected session" window and IDE hangs. x86 debugging works as expected. All other packages are enabled as dafault. Maybe someone know how GetIt touches x64 debugger? I'm very curious.

Comment: Just to rule out other causes: can you work as expected when GetIt is reenabled?

Comment: Yes, I test it many times. All work as expected after reenabling GetIt.

Comment: I setup a clean virtual machine and test it there. x64 debuggign works also with GetIt disabled. Very strange!

Answer (score -1):

It works when you use this: [Using the -r command line switch to fix start up errors in the IDE](http://support.embarcadero.com/article/42597) .
Below is an image of a little tool I built to manage that. 
Free compiled Tool is downloadable from here: [XE8RegHivePackageManager.zip](http://members.shaw.ca/f.s/XE8RegHivePackageManager.zip)

[image: XE8 Package Manager Image]

Comment: That looks potentially very handy.  Problem is, being compiled, it's indistinguishable from a malware day-zero pov from the sort of stuff a disgruntled user such as the author of this q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021226/delphi-split-linesprogram-not-responding-not-spliting-file-size-tthread might post to extract revenge.  (Obviously that wasn't you because he was plainly incapable of coding anything, but you get my point I'm sure).  Maybe post it in source form?

Comment: I don't mind giving away the source but then someone would need to go and strip out proprietary functions (essentially record helper functions) and I don't have time for that.. at least not right now..

Comment: Fair enough.  Sometimes I wonder why there isn't some kind of collaborative code repository built-in to SO for this sort of thing.  Maybe there is, but I've never noticed it mentioned, nor wanted to ask about it for fear of being shouted down by the off-topic police.

Comment: I downvoted this because I cannot see any explanation of how getit interacts with the x64 debugger